# django max and groupby together

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model which looks like this
player_info, game, score, creation_date

I want to fetch the records with the highest score of each player for a particular game.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    logo = models.URLField()
    resource_info = models.URLField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    developer_info = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_games', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Score(models.Model):
    game_info = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='game_info',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_info = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='player_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_played = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code ? Like the relevant models with all the relevant fields ? And also what query/queries you tried.

Comment: this is how my model look like

class Score(models.Model):
    game_info = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='game_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_info = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='player_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_played = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
class Game(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
resource_info = models.URLField()developer_info = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uploaded_games', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

- You want to `filter` your `Score`s by a `Game`.
- And then you want to `GROUP BY` `User` and get the `MAX` score

The `GROUP BY` part is a bit tricky, but you can achieve it using `values` + `annotate`.

Try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Score.objects.filter(game_info=...)
    .values('player_info').annotate(max=Max('score'))
```

More info an examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/